# Sort entire DataTables on selected text in columns containing select elements when pagination is used

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using DataTables for my tables. I am having a few columns with select elements. What I want is to sort those columns based on the text that is selected. In all examples I can find, the sorting is based on the value, not the text.

This is the example which is the standard way of doing it (with the exception that I convert the column to visible) and sorts on the value.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-select'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn, iColumnVis)
    {  
            iColumn = oSettings.oApi._fnColumnIndexToVisible( oSettings, iColumn );

        var aData = [];


$( 'td:eq('+iColumn+') select', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings) ).each( function () {
        aData.push( $(this).val() );

    } );
    return aData;
};
```

What I have tried to do is extract the text and push it to aData. Some of the options that has been selected is just empty.

Instead of "aData.push( $(this).val() );" I do this:

```
if($.trim($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " option:selected").text())!=""){
         aData.push($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " option:selected").text());
    }else{ 
         aData.push("");
}
```

I sorts but still not in alphabetic order. And it only sort the visible rows, not the rows I have to paginate to.

However, it seems to work fine when I chose to view enough rows so all existing rows can be presented on one single page (hence, no pagination needed to view some other rows).

How can I achieve sorting on the entire table using the select elements selected text when pagination is used?

**UPDATE**

My table config (I copied aoColumnDefs and covis from firebug (since I am constructing those on server side), hence the format may not be 100% correct in my config below but the content is the same):

```
$('#mytickettable').dataTable( {              
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "oLanguage": {                          
            "sUrl": "https://" + hostname + "/modules/core/localization/locale/" + lang.user_locale + "/LC_MESSAGES/datatables.tr",
             "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
         },
         "iDisplayLength": 25,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "sDom": 'RHF<"top"TClpf>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
         "oTableTools": { 
             "aButtons": [{
                  "sExtends":    "text",
                  "sButtonText": lang.localized_text.SHOW_HIDE_TICKET_OVERVIEW,
                   "fnClick": ticketoverview_handler                                         
                 },
                 { "sExtends":    "text",
                   "sButtonText": lang.localized_text.SHOW_HIDE_QUICK_FILTER,
                   "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                      $("#agentfilterform").toggle();
                      $("#show_closed_tickets").toggle();
                      if(page=='myticketsmenu'){
                           $("#agentfilter_asigned_ownerform").toggle();
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                     "sExtends":    "text",
                     "sButtonText": lang.localized_text.REFRESH_TABLE,
                     "fnClick": function ( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                                 oTable.fnReloadAjax();
                      }
                   },                                                                        
                   {
                      "sExtends": "xls",  
                      "sButtonText": "Excel",
                      "sAction": "flash_save",
                      "sFileName": "Ticketlist.xls",                                        
                      "mColumns": "visible"
                   },  
                   {
                      "sExtends": "csv",
                      "sButtonText": "CSV",
                      "sFileName": "Ticketlist.csv",
                      "sAction": "flash_save",
                      "mColumns": "visible"
//                    "bShowAll": false
                    }]
                },
          "oColVis": {
               "aiExclude": [12],
               "bRestore": true,
               "buttonText": lang.localized_text.SHOW_HIDE_COLUMNS,
               "iOverlayFade": 0
          },
          "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
          "aoColumnDefs": 
               [{"asSorting":["desc","asc","desc"],"aTargets":[0]},  
                {"sWidth":"50px","aTargets":[0]},
                {"sWidth":"65px","aTargets":[3]}, 
                {"sWidth":"175px","aTargets":[4]},
                {"sWidth":"110px","aTargets":[5]},
                {"sWidth":"110px","aTargets":[6]},
                {"sWidth":"125px","aTargets":[7]},
                {"sWidth":"110px","aTargets":[8]},
                {"sSortDataType":"dom-select","aTargets":[3]},
                {"sSortDataType":"dom-select","aTargets":[5]},
                {"sSortDataType":"dom-select","aTargets":[6]},
                {"bVisible":false,"aTargets":[9]},
                {"bVisible":false,"aTargets":[10]},
                {"bSearchable":true,"aTargets":[11]},
                {"bSearchable":true,"aTargets":[12]},
                {"bVisible":false,"aTargets":[12]},
                {"sSortDataType":"dom-select","aTargets":[1]},
                {"bVisible":false,"aTargets":[1]},
                {"bSearchable":true,"aTargets":[1]},
                {"sWidth":"65px","aTargets":[1]},
                {"sSortDataType":"dom-select","aTargets":[2]},
                {"sWidth":"75px","aTargets":[2]}]                       
                ,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bStateSave": false,                 
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "https://" + hostname + "/modules/core/ticket/get_ticket_list.php",
                "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {                             
                          aoData.push({"name":"show_closed", "value":show_closed});
                          aoData.push({"name":"page", "value":page});
                 },
                 "fnInitComplete": tablesetuphandler,
                 "fnPreDrawCallback": function(oSettings){
                       var $tableRow = $('#mytickettable tbody tr:eq(' + markedRow + ')');
                       $($tableRow).removeClass('row_selected');
                  },
                  "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings){   
                  $(".ColVis_Button").button(); //fixbutton                            
                       if (tableInitiated) {
                              markedRow = markNewRow(0,0 );
                              var table = document.getElementById("mytickettable");
                              var row = table.rows[markedRow+1];
                              var cell = row.cells[id_index];
                              var $id = cell.firstChild.nodeValue;                                    
                              if(oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay()==0){
                              }else if(old_id!=$id && oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay()>0){
                                   load_ticket_overview($id);
                              }                                
                         }

                  }

         });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have the full picture of what you're doing, but what happens when you try this for your `aData.push()`?

```
aData.push( $(":selected", this).text() );
```

When I try this with the [live dom sort example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html) available in the datatables download, 
paging and sorting appear to be working ok when I enter text that differs from the option values.

Comment: Thanks but no difference actually. I'm updating my question with the table configuration as well. Not really sure how to debug this, any suggestion? When printing the text to the column, it's the correct text that is printed. Can it be any problem that I have some selected texts that are empty?

Comment: Actually, this was the correct way. But since I also made a check to see if the text was empty using my way, it didn't work anyway. Now it works, see my own answer where I elaborate. But why didn't my way work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved based on @mg1075's suggestion, but I elaborate somewhat here!

Since I was having some problems I thought it could be that I had some text of the selected values empty. To mitigate this I checked if the text was empty and than just did aData.push("") if that was the case.

The way I checked if the value was empty was like this:

```
if($.trim($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " option:selected").text())!=""){}
```

This was also the way I was pushing the data to aData (except trim, but I didn't matter since printing it out with trimming still didn't recognize all texts (see below).

```
aData.push($("#" + $(this).attr('id') + " option:selected").text())
```

Now this strange thing which I don't understand; the only time that the trimmed text wasn't empty was when the word "Problem" was the selected text. When it was "Incident" or anything else it was considered empty. **Please if anyone can have any theory, why is that?**

So @mg1075 was actually right that I should use aData.push( $(":selected", this).text() ); instead. But first when I tried it I didn't use it when checking if it was empty but only for pushing the data. Now I only use aData.push( $.trim($(":selected", this).text())); to add the data, I don't check if it is empty or not since it works anyways.